# How to use Google Apps Script code in my pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm building a web app using HTML, CSS and JavaScript and using Google Spreadsheet as a database. I'm planning to use PhoneGap to turn my web app into a real app.

I was able to read from my Google Sheet, using the Google Visualization API, now I'm working about the writing options: I used a function set with Google Apps Script, inside the Google Spreadsheet and it works correctly.

A great user of this site gave me the advice to use this command to go back to my pages:`return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('redirect').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);`

and told me to create the redirect page, in which a simple JS function uses `window.location.href` to go back to my pages. In this way, the address is the same of the script, but I need it to be mine, because I cannot run my app in an iframe.

Long story short, I want that the address in my browser to be mine and not use GAS sandbox to navigate my site.

I wasn't able to find a solution so I'm here again for the millionth time... is there a way to use Google Apps Script functions in my own pages, maybe calling some APIs in it? In this way I'm sure I could use some line of standard code to go back where I need.

This is the function code:

```
    function doPost(e){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID").getSheetByName('SheetName');
    var column = 1; 
    var colArray = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, colArray);


    var id = maxi+1;
    var name = e.parameter['name'];
    var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
    var serial = e.parameter['serial'];
    var eMail = e.parameter['mail'];
    var text = e.parameter['text'];
    var area = e.parameter['area'];
    var date = new Date();
    var ans = ""
    var flag = "Work In Progress";

    var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, area, text, ans, flag];

    var sheetObj = sheet.appendRow(vals);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('redirect').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

and that's the page:

```
        <html>
          <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            function test()
            {
               window.location.href = "myAdd";
            }
        </script>
          </head>
          <body onload="test()">
          </body>
        </html>
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: From your web page, you can make an AJAX request to the published URL of an Apps Script Web App.  [Mozilla Developer documentation - AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)  You can send a "payload" in a POST request to the `doPost(e)` function in a stand alone Apps Script file.

Comment: Something like `httpRequest.open('POST', 'myGAS', true);
httpRequest.send($('#myFormID').serialize());` ? I'm not very confident with AJAX

Comment: I don't have much experience with AJAX either.  I don't have a quick example for you.  If your website has server side code, you can also make a POST request from the hosts server to the Apps Script Web App.  Or, you can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/)

Comment: Yes, I tried with Google Sheets APIs but I wasn't able to find a clear example that helped me to write my code in JS. I have to use JavaScript because I'm planning to convert my webapp in a real one using Phonegap and the software processes HTML, CSS and JS...

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to use Google Sheet API with JavaScript and not with Java? I cannot use Java because of PhoneGap conversion...

Comment: Well, the Google Sheets API is a REST API.  It has different SDK's for different server side languages, but you don't need to use any of the SDK's.  You can make HTTPS requests from anything.  So, I think it is possible to use the Google Sheets API from client side code, if you used AJAX.  But, if you already have Apps Script code doing what you want it to do, then I'd just make an AJAX request to the URL of the published Web App.

Comment: Ok I read the whole API to make a HTTPS request: I found this `POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:append` but I have two questions:
1) How can I found the range I need? I thought I could count the number of full rows in my spreadsheet, add the value in a cell, read this value and make the request from this parameter, but I'm not sure I can do it.
2) This code will append my data or overwrite the spreadsheet?

Could you kindly provide me an example of a "complete" request via HTTPS? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run Google Scripts outside of GAS

Answer (score 0):

If your project can accomodate that (if, for example, you have a form and you want it to write on a spreadsheet) perhaps you could try to use the [REST Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run) and pass the proper payload so that you can run your script RPC-style.

Comment: I added _some_ details, hoping it can define in a better way what I need.... Thanks for your quick reply!